# Mulitple ULs handled by one click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML that is essentially a few of `ul` lists.

The `li` elements inside are dynamically generated based on results of an ajax call.

If I separate all of them out (a `change` event for each ID of each UL) it works fine. But that isn't very DRY and seems like a waste of code.

My HTML is this:

```
<ul id="id_camp" class="registration-data-option">
    <li><label for="id_camp_0"><input type="radio" name="camp" value="1" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_camp_0"> Camp One</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_camp_1"><input type="radio" name="camp" value="2" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_camp_1"> Another Camp</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_camp_2"><input type="radio" name="camp" value="3" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_camp_2"> PE Camp</label></li>
</ul>
<ul id="id_class" class="registration-data-option">
    <li><label for="id_class_0"><input type="radio" name="class" value="1" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_class_0"> class One</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_class_1"><input type="radio" name="class" value="2" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_class_1"> Another class</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_class_2"><input type="radio" name="class" value="3" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_class_2"> PE class</label></li>
</ul>
<ul id="id_location" class="registration-data-option">
    <li><label for="id_location_0"><input type="radio" name="location" value="1" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_location_0"> location One</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_location_1"><input type="radio" name="location" value="2" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_location_1"> Another location</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_location_2"><input type="radio" name="location" value="3" class="registration-data-option" required="" id="id_location_2"> PE location</label></li>
</ul>
```

Initially - the only options shown are the camps. Then the second UL is returned from the ajax call. Once that is selected, it should show the third UL, etc.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

A dynamic / linked dropdown system where the next dropdown shows up after the user selects the first one as the data is dynamically generated.

My jquery looks like this:

```
    $(".registration-data-option").change(function(event) {
        var target_id = $(event.target).closest('ul').attr('id') // id_camp, id_class, id_location
        var url = $("#registrationForm").attr("data-choices-update-url");
        var camp_id = $('#id_camp').find('input:checked').val()
        var class_id = $('#id_class').find('input:checked').val()
        var location_id = $('#id_location').find('input:checked').val()
        var person_id = $('#id_person').find(":selected").val()
        $.ajax({
            url: url, //this returns data - which is an HTML snippet
            data: {
                'target_id': target_id,
                'camp_id': camp_id,
                'class_id': class_id,
                'location_id': location_id,
                'person_id': person_id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var class_html = $(data).get(0).innerHTML
                var location_html = $(data).get(2).innerHTML
                $("#id_class").html(class_html)
                $("#id_location").html(location_html)
                $(event.target).prop('checked',true)
            }
        });
    });
```

Lastly, the HTML snippet getting returned from the AJAX looks like this:

```
<div id="classChoices">
    {% for class in classes %}
        <li>
            <label for="id_class_{{ forloop.counter }}">
                <input type="radio"
                    name="class"
                    class="registration-data-option"
                    value="{{ class.pk }}"
                    required
                    id="id_class_{{ forloop.counter }}">
                {{ class.name }}
            </label>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div id="locationChoices">
    {% for location in locations %}
        <li>
            <label for="id_location_{{ forloop.counter }}">
                <input type="radio"
                    name="location"
                    class="registration-data-option"
                    value="{{ location.pk }}"
                    required
                    id="id_location_{{ forloop.counter }}">
                {{ location.name }}
            </label>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Current Issue:**
It only partially works. If I select a 'camp', then the appropriate classes are displayed. Once you click on a class - then the appropriate locations show up - but then class is *unchecked*. If you click on a location, then it all disappears because there is no class selected.

Just trying to figure it all out.

Comment: one thing I note (although it may not affect anything), giving your `<ul>`s the class `class="registration-data-option"` doesn't make any logical sense - you're not trying to handle a "change" event on those...its the radio buttons which are the thing you're targeting

Comment: Would that `registration-data-option` being on the `ul` and the `li` cause it to fire twice? Once because the `ul` changed and once because the `li` changed?

Comment: The event is on the `<ul>` and the `<input>`s no? `<li>` is not involved. Anyway I'm not sure what would happen without trying it...you can easily stick some console.log commands in (or just step through the code in the browser debugger) to see if that's true. Even if not, it still makes more sense to remove the class from the `<ul>`s - if nothing else it's confusing for those trying to maintain the code in future. When I first saw your code I saw the change event was actually targeting the `<ul>`s...and thought it didn't make much sense. Took a minute before I noticed it was on the inputs too

Comment: Absolutely, I agree and intend on removing it from the UL items. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that

> " the appropriate locations show up - but then class is unchecked."

...that's because you always replace the "class" HTML, no matter what (using `$("#id_class").html(class_html)`). This removes the HTML which had the radio button which the user selected, and replaces it with a completely brand set of HTML from the server, which of course contains no information about what the user had previously done with the HTML it replaced.

Since you've already got the `target_id` information, you can use that to know which (bits) of HTML need replacing each time (e.g. I think if the target is location then you don't need to replace the class HTML).

e.g.

```
if (target_id != "id_location") $("#id_class").html(class_html)
```

Of course that's simplistic if you wanted this to be completely dynamic over an unpredictable number of layers. But you get the idea - you must use the current context to decide what to do with the HTML.

An alternative option (instead of the above) is to change the server side code so that it uses the `class_id` value you sent it in the AJAX parameters to write the HTML it returns such that the correct radio button is already pre-checked via the markup.